# Modify value in the object containing a particular string using jq

Tags: json, jq, edit

I am trying to modify a large json file (a Grafana dashboard), replacing a single value, then output the whole file with the change. How can I do this?

You can see the value I want to edit here. The actual file is quite large, so there are many other top-level values, but I only need to edit a specific item under the "templating" block.

```
"templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "allValue": ".*",
        "current": {},
        "datasource": "$Source",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": false,
        "label": null,
        "multi": true,
        "name": "node",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(node_boot_time{env=~\"$env\"}, instance)",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
      {
        "allValue": null,
        "current": {
          "tags": [],
          "text": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        "datasource": "$Source",
        "definition": "label_values(env)",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": "env",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "env",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(env)",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 1,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
      {
        "current": {
          "tags": [],
          "text": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": false,
        "label": null,
        "multi": false,
        "name": "Source",
        "options": [],
        "query": "prometheus",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "type": "datasource"
      }
    ]
  },
```

The piece I need to change is the block containing `"query": "label_values(env)",` and I just need to change the value of `"regex": "",`

I have tried:

```
jq '.templating.list[] | select(.name == "env") |= . + {regex:"*"}' "dashboard.json" > test.json
```

The problem is then it only prints the ".list[]" elements instead of the whole file. I need to be able to make this change for multiple other files that will have the same block, but not necessarily in the same place so I can't just select by index number.

Output of above script:

```
{
  "allValue": ".*",
  "current": {},
  "datasource": "$Source",
  "hide": 0,
  "includeAll": false,
  "label": null,
  "multi": true,
  "name": "node",
  "options": [],
  "query": "label_values(node_boot_time{env=~\"$env\"}, instance)",
  "refresh": 1,
  "regex": "",
  "sort": 0,
  "tagValuesQuery": "",
  "tags": [],
  "tagsQuery": "",
  "type": "query",
  "useTags": false
}
{
  "allValue": null,
  "current": {
    "tags": [],
    "text": "",
    "value": ""
  },
  "datasource": "$Source",
  "definition": "label_values(env)",
  "hide": 0,
  "includeAll": true,
  "label": "env",
  "multi": false,
  "name": "env",
  "options": [],
  "query": "label_values(env)",
  "refresh": 1,
  "regex": "*",
  "skipUrlSync": false,
  "sort": 1,
  "tagValuesQuery": "",
  "tags": [],
  "tagsQuery": "",
  "type": "query",
  "useTags": false
}
{
  "current": {
    "tags": [],
    "text": "",
    "value": ""
  },
  "hide": 0,
  "includeAll": false,
  "label": null,
  "multi": false,
  "name": "Source",
  "options": [],
  "query": "prometheus",
  "refresh": 1,
  "regex": "",
  "skipUrlSync": false,
  "type": "datasource"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position `|=` earlier to retain the original structure.

```
.templating.list[] |= (select(.name == "env") .regex = "*")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EcYC0-_7X6)</sup>

Comment: That works, thanks! Also I was unaware of jq play, very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output isn't quite matching with your description of your problem. If your requirement is to find inside `templating` list find the query containing `"label_values(env)"` and update the `regex` to `""` you need below. To change it to `*`, use `regex = "*"`

```
.templating.list[] |= ( select(.query == "label_values(env)").regex = "")
```

The key is to use the right path and use the select operator to get the object to update using the `|=` operator

[jq-play snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/Z4-MMkKRyG)